# Suppression of the mixing angle of the heavy neutrino in medium

Tags: quantum-field-theory, neutrinos, propagator, effective-field-theory

Consider a fermion $N$ with mass $m_{N}$ and coupling to an active neutrino $\nu$ via the mixing
$$
\mathcal{L} = m_{N}\theta \bar{N}\nu,
$$
where $\theta\ll 1$ is the mixing angle.

It is known that in the hot plasma medium the mixing angle is suppressed:
$$
\tag 1 \theta_{M} = \frac{\theta}{1+f(T,m_{N})},
$$
with $f(T)$ being some temperature-dependent function. I have tried to derive this formula using the general form of the interaction of $N$ with SM particles: for $N$ in the final state, we have

$$
\tag 2 \mathcal{M} = \theta m_{N}\bar{N}D_{\nu}(p,T)\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})\dots,
$$
where $\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})$ originates from the interaction of active neutrinos with other particles (neutrinos, leptons), $\dots$ denote the interaction dependent part, and $D_{\nu}(p,T)$ is the neutrino propagator. In the plasma it acquires a form
$$
D_{\nu}(p,T) =\frac{1}{\hat{p} - \Sigma}, \quad \Sigma = -A(T)\hat{c}(1-\gamma_{5}),  \quad \hat{x} \equiv x^{\mu}\gamma_{\mu},
$$
where $A(T)\ll 1$, and $c^{\mu}$ is the model-dependent vector (a combination of plasma 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$ and 4-momentum $p$). In the case of hot charge-symmetric plasma with 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$ it has the form
$$
c^{\mu} = (p\cdot u)u^{\mu} - p^{\mu}/4,
$$
I expect to get
$$
\boxed{\mathcal{M} = \theta_{M}\bar{N}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})\dots}
$$
However, using some transformations ($\gamma$ matrices identities, Dirac equation, neglecting the $A^{2}$ terms), I obtain
$$
\mathcal{M} \approx \theta_{M} \bar{N}\left(1+2A \frac{\hat{c}}{m_{N}}\right)\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})\dots, \quad \theta_{M} = \frac{\theta}{1+4A \frac{c\cdot p}{m_{N}^{2}}}
$$
The denominator for $\theta_{M}$ turns out to be fully correct, but what disturbs me is the $2A \hat{c}/m_{N}$ term in the numerator: it maybe should disappear. Because of this, I have a question: is the method of obtaining Eq. (1) based on Eq. (2) correct, and if yes, why do people neglect the extra term in the numerator (it may be large and hence non-negligible)?